# Visual or UML tool to draw micro service connectivity

Tags: architecture, uml, microservices, tool-uml

what is the best way to represent microservice and their connection to each other via UML diagram? any open source tool to create UML/Visualize the different microservice and their connections?

Comment: The good old DIA comes to mind: [DIA on SF](https://sourceforge.net/projects/dia-installer/)

Comment: What is so special about microservices? Any UML tool will do. Try google Search or Wikipedia for a vast collection of tools, including freeware (some open source, some closed). The questions about what software can I use generally are considered as not fitting into SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use whatever is best works for you.
I prefer:
https://www.draw.io/
http://plantuml.com/ - in the wiki (confluence)

Answer (score 0):

Here is another one (website states it works on both mac and pc) with free trial [ConeptDraw](http://www.conceptdraw.com/solution-park/software-uml)